# Show the Set of Polynomials of Degree $\le n$, Uniformly Bounded in a compact $C$ is Equicontinuous in $C$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, equicontinuity

**Problem**

Show the Set of Polynomial $(p(x))$ of Degree $\le n$, Uniformly Bounded in a compact $C$ is Equicontinuous in $C$.

**I know what to do** but I don't understand it very well.

I've seen answers that goes as follows:

We can assume without loss of generality (**I don't get why**), that our compact $C$ is $[-1,1]$. Now we can use [Markov Brothers' Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_brothers%27_inequality), which gives us:

$$\sup_{x\in [-1, 1]}|p'(x)| \le n^2 \sup_{x\in [-1, 1]}|p(x)|$$

for all polynomial p of degree $\le n$, therefore (**I also don't understand the right-hand side of this step**)

$$p'(x)\le n^2$$

so, as this holds for all polynomial in my set and for all $x\in [-1,1]$, we have that the set is equicontinuous.

Now, I really don't get the conclusion. How can this show that $\forall \epsilon >0 \enspace \exists \delta >0$ such that $x,x_0 \in \enspace C, |x-x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow |p(x)-p(x_0)|<\epsilon \enspace $ for every polynomial in my set of polynomials?

Sorry if I'm asking too much but I really don't follow the reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1)$Every compact set on the real line is contained on some closed interval $[a,b]$

So there is a bijective continuous and differentiable function $s:[a,b] \to [-1,1]$

For instance $s(x)=\frac{x-a}{b-a}+\frac{x-b}{b-a}$

So you can work with the polynomial $p(s(x))$  the same way you worked with $p(x)$

$2)$Since the set $S$ is uniformly bounded ,then exists $M>0$  such that $\sup_{[-1,1]}|p(x)| \leq M,\forall p \in S$

Thus $|p'(x)| \leq n^2M,\forall x \in [-1,1],\forall p \in S$

So it does not matter here if the bound is $n^2$ (which may not be correct) The whole point  of the exercise is the finding of a uniform bounded of the derivatives of the polynomials.

$3)$By M.V.T you have  for every polynomial $p$ of degree less than $n$  that $|p(x)-p(y)| \leq Mn^2|x-y|$

Since $C=Mn^2$ does not depend on the choice of the polynomial,you can prove now equicontinuity.

Comment: on you very first sentence: what about a union of 2 disjoint intervals, not even mentioning about sets like Cantor set on [0,1]. Compact on real line is equivalent to being closed and bounded.

Comment: @Hayk Your are right..i had the intervals in my mind